# is correct for eval for javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, math, eval

I have this code here is this correct for the javascript eval usage if not can u help me?

```
<form name="Adder" action="adder(Adder)">
<input type="number" name="num1" />
<b><h4>+</H4></b>
<input type="number" name="num2" />
<input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>

<p>Your answer shoud appear here:</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function adder(Adder) {
eval("x=num1;y=num2;document.write(x+y)");
}
</script>
```

This is the code i am talking about that html with javascript.

Comment: Why do you think `eval` was necessary here? You're evaluating a static string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, [you can't use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write#Notes) `document.write` once the document is loaded and you don't need `eval` here.

You can do this :

```
<form>
  <input id=num1 type="number" name="num1" />
  <b><h4>+</h4></b>
  <input id=num2 type="number" name="num2" />
  <input id=Add type="button" value=Add />
</form>

<p>Your answer shoud appear here:</p><span id=sum></span

<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById('Add').onclick=function() {
     var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('num1').value);
     var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('num2').value);
     document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = num1 + num2;
   }
</script>
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/omIQuXE/2/)

Note that

- I give an id to the three needed elements to get them more easily
- I use `parseFloat` to convert the values from strings to numbers
- I use `innerHTML` to write the result in the paragraph
- Your adding function don't use any argument
- You don't need an `action` in your form or a `submit` input if you don't want to submit
- You could also remove the `form`
- Indentation makes the code more readable
- there would be comments to make also about the `h4` in a `b` but it's starting to be too much

Comment: `onsubmit="adder(); return false;"` instead of the action attribute you just removed would work too.

Comment: thanks sooo mch join us on codecadamy the group  is TheOpenCodeWare